# When i Turned on my system today, instead of the GUI. It’s displaying a command line

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gui

[Laptop Screen as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Zqa.jpg)

This is what my laptop is showing when I opened up today.

Please help me to fix this, i am panicking so much.

I can login. But i am only seeing my terminal.

I dont have any technical sophistication experience with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen yesterday on 23.04. I went to advanced options in grub, and selected the generic kernel in recovery mode. Do all the repair routines listed that it will let you do. I can't remember what they were, and then boot normally and you should get into the gui. I had the same thing happen several times when I rebooted, then it stopped happening, and I could just boot as normal. I'm no expert on this, but I figured I'd try to help. Since I just dealt with this.